# Building android app via ant won't work from batch file?

Tags: android, ant

I'm trying to build my android app via commandline (batch file to be specific). I'm working on a phonegap/cordova app and I find it to be a bit of an overkill to use Eclipse only for compiling.

If I try it via commandline it works. But if I run it in a batch file it looks like ANT is using JRE instead of JDK??

```
    Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\tools.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use javac in ant then you need `tools.jar` to work it properly. You can find this answer on [apache ant site](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html) (`When you need JDK functionality (such as for the javac task or the rmic task), then tools.jar must be added. The scripts supplied with Ant, in the bin directory, will add the required JDK classes automatically, if the JAVA_HOME environment variable is set.`).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this happens. But you would usually find tools.jar in C:\ProgramFiles\Java\JDK\lib

Copying that to the C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jre\lib folder would make it work without any change to the JAVA_HOME